# Content Editor not updating in Sitecore when I programatically update/add content

Tags: api, editor, sitecore

I am programatically adding/editing content in the master DB, and I know it saves correctly because if I run another 'app', I can see the content I created/updated.
However I can't see the content in the content editor.  However if I go to the 'template' associated with the content I create/edited, and make a minor change, and save it.  I get the message 'Updating content' which I expect to see... (it is applying the template change to the content).
Then I can see the content I created/edited...
So it appears that something needs to be triggered that modifying the template triggers that I am not.
Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: What code do you use to update the content programatically? What do you mean by "can't see the content"? Any code examples / screenshots?

Comment: What I mean by 'cant see the content' is that it doesn't show up in the content tree in the UI.  Yet I can query it using the API.  If I edit the 'template' associated with the content type, then it suddenly appears in the content tree.  I am following the example: [link](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems2.aspx)

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are updating an item or a template? If you clear all caches after you programmatically make the change, do you see it then? (This shouldn't be necessary but could help pinpoint the issue.) You can clear the caches at /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx

Comment: I am creating/updating items programatically... the only way I can see it is if I go to the 'templates', and modify the template and save, which then triggers the updating of all content, at which time it appears in the content tree in the UI.  I will try the 'cache' clear as you suggested, and let you know.

Comment: Could you add the sourcecode you use to create the item? I've recently seen that creating an item through the API resulted in orphan-items (without a parent) in some special occasions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the input.  The issue is that the cache is not being cleared.  Collapsing/Expanding the tree did not work.  I literally had to clear the cache and it worked.  Thank you all.  Hope if anyone else has this issue, my answer helps them!

Answer (score 0):

The content tree won't automatically update following external changes to the content structure (eg another user adding/deleting something under the node you are looking at).  If you collapse and expand the parent node of where your content is programmatically created, that should be enough to show the newly created content.

Comment: In my experience, it is necessary to manually expire the cache (e.g. using /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx) to force content added through the back end to appear.